# 〜で〜て欲しい rather than 〜に〜て欲しい: a mistake?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-で

> 逢桜「いえ、わたしの後悔を先輩**で**晴らして欲しいですから」

I understand from the story that 逢桜 doesn’t want her 先輩 to make the same mistake as 逢桜 did, so she says "I want senpai to clear my regrets". But why is で used here? Shouldn’t it be に? Or is there anything wrong with this usage?

Comment: Who is she talking to? The 先輩, or someone else?

Comment: @naruto She is talking to the 先輩.

Answer (score 1):

で is not particularly unnatural while 先輩に is possible and equally natural  (less naturally 先輩が).

One way to understand is to consider there is an omission (e.g.): 先輩(の番)で *in Senpai's turn*.  It is a little hard to guess, but suppose the characters are trying to achieve something and 逢桜 failed. Then Senpai will give a try soon, then the sentence in question means something like *I would feel the revenge is done (to the thing I failed) if you succeed, and I wish for it*.